# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class iland.hbm.BillProductDetails

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to save data in different table
for that I am writing main method as
Here I want to save BillDetails bd, along with CustomerDetails cd(If exist updated otherwise inserted)and BillProductDetails bpd while saving it is giving exception
`Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class iland.hbm.BillProductDetails`

```
 public static void main(String[] s) {
        BillDetails bd = new BillDetails();
        bd.setPaymentType("Cash");
        DatenTime dnt = new DatenTime();
        bd.setAddDate(dnt.getTimeStamp());
        bd.setSubTotal(400f);
        bd.setVat(20f);
        bd.setTotal(420f);
        /*Customer details*/
        CustomerDetails cd = new CustomerDetails();
        cd.setId(107L);
        cd.setName("Nita");
        cd.setAddress("India");
        cd.setDob(new Date(2014, 11, 1));
        cd.setAnniversery(new Date(2014, 11, 1));
        bd.setCustomerDetails(cd);
        /*Bill Product Details*/
        BillProductDetails bpd = new BillProductDetails();
        bpd.setQty(4);
        bpd.setSellingPrice(420.0F);
        bpd.setUnitPrice(400.0F);
        bpd.setDiscountPercent(10);
        ProductDetails pd = new ProductDetails();
        pd.setBarcode("111");
        pd.setId(1001L);
        bpd.setProductDetails(pd);
        bpd.setBillDetails(bd);
        bd.getBillProductList().add(bpd);
        BillDAO dao = new BillDAO();
        dao.insert(bd);

    }
```

BillDetails.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="iland.hbm.BillDetails" table="bill_details" catalog="retail_shop">
        <id name="billNo" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="bill_no" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="customerDetails" class="iland.hbm.CustomerDetails" fetch="select" cascade="all">
            <column name="customer_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="client" class="iland.hbm.Client" fetch="select" cascade="all">
            <column name="cid" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="subTotal" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="sub_total" precision="15" />
        </property>
        <property name="vat" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="vat" precision="15" />
        </property>
        <property name="total" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="total" precision="15" />
        </property>
        <property name="paymentType" type="string">
            <column name="payment_type" length="30" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="status" type="string">
            <column name="status" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="addDate" type="timestamp">
            <column name="add_date" length="19" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <bag name="billProductList" table="bill_product_details" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="join" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="bill_no" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="iland.hbm.BillProductDetails" />
        </bag>
        <set name="billPaidDetailses" table="bill_paid_details" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="join" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="bill_no" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="iland.hbm.BillPaidDetails" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

BillProductDetails.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="iland.hbm.BillProductDetails" table="bill_product_details" catalog="retail_shop">
        <composite-id name="id" class="iland.hbm.BillProductDetailsId">
            <key-property name="productId" type="long">
                <column name="product_id" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="billNo" type="long">
                <column name="bill_no" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <many-to-one name="client" class="iland.hbm.Client" fetch="select">
            <column name="cid" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="billDetails" class="iland.hbm.BillDetails" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="bill_no" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="productDetails" class="iland.hbm.ProductDetails" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="product_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="qty" type="long">
            <column name="qty" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="unitPrice" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="unit_price" precision="15" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="sellingPrice" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="selling_price" precision="15" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="discountPercent" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="discount_percent" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

DAO

```
public class BillDAO {

    public int insert(BillDetails obj) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(obj);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return 1;
    }
```

Exception:

```
  Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class iland.hbm.BillProductDetails
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:685)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:697)
    at iland.bill.BillDAO.insert(BillDAO.java:30)
    at iland.bill.BillNewAction.main(BillNewAction.java:76)
```

How to resolve this.

Edit:
My `BillDetails` Pojo

```
public class BillDetails implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long billNo;
    private CustomerDetails customerDetails;
    private Client client;
    private BigDecimal subTotal;
    private BigDecimal vat;
    private BigDecimal total;
    private String paymentType;
    private String status;
    private Timestamp addDate;
    private Set billPaidDetailses = new HashSet(0);
    private List<BillProductDetails> billProductList = new ArrayList<BillProductDetails>();
    //getter setter
```

}

```
 public class BillProductDetails  implements java.io.Serializable {

 private BillProductDetailsId id;
 private Client client;
 private BillDetails billDetails;
 private ProductDetails productDetails;
 private long qty;
 private BigDecimal unitPrice;
 private BigDecimal sellingPrice;
 private Integer discountPercent;
 //getter and setter
}

 public class BillProductDetailsId  implements java.io.Serializable {
 private long productId;
 private long billNo;
 //getter and setter
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
session.close();
```

at the end of your insert() method too.

Make sure the Cascade.ALL is set for:

- billDetails.billProductList
- billProductDetails.productDetails
- billProductDetails.billDetails

Make sure all id's have the @Id and the @GeneratedValue set

```
@Id @GeneratedValue
Integer getId() { ... };
```

You mapping has:

```
<bag name="billProductList" table="bill_product_details" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="join" cascade="all">
        <key>
            <column name="bill_no" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="iland.hbm.BillProductDetails" />
</bag>

<many-to-one name="billDetails" class="iland.hbm.BillDetails" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="bill_no" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
```

So, if you choose your bag to be "inverse" you need to have the many-to-one side in control of this association. Therefore you need to remove the:

- update="false"
- insert="false"

From the

You could also have the one-to-many be in control, which would mean to remove the "inverse" property, but this is not advisable, since it will always delete/reinsert whenever you change the list content.

This way this end will be able to control the association.

Comment: I have done that changes. I added pojos at my question plese see

Comment: I still don't see the actual mapping annotations like onetomany and manytoone, along with the cascade setting.

Comment: Check my updated response. I think you made both ends to ignore the association.